# Data validation for RDS PostgreSQL migration

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, amazon-dms, data-validation

I'm planning to replace a bunch of RDS PostgreSQL databases using [this method defined by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/encrypt-an-existing-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-db-instance.html).

[image: Migration method]

The DMS task will run will be CDC-only. I came up with data validation requirements for the migration and am open to feedback.

## Requirements

1. If a table **has a PK**, validate it using AWS DMS.
2. If a table has a column that would be considered LOB, such as JSON, validate the column by hashing specific column on the source and target, then diffing the sums (method A).
3. If a table doesn’t have a primary key but has a column that is effectively unique, but not declared as `UNIQUE` in the schema, validate the table using WbDataDiff (method B). The effectively unique column will be specified as the alternate key (`--alternateKey`).
4. If a table doesn’t have a primary key and has no unique columns, validate the table by hashing a set of columns with highly variable data on the source and target, then diffing the sums (method A).

## Validation Methods

A. Hash a single column or set of columns with highly variable data and diff.

- This method can validate LOB migration, e.g. JSON columns.
- This method can validate tables that don't have a primary key or any effectively `UNIQUE` column.
- SQL below came from [this source](https://www.sisense.com/blog/hashing-tables-to-ensure-consistency-in-postgres-redshift-and-mysql/).

```
SELECT
    -- Prepends an x the extracted first 8 characters of the hash
    -- (generates a hash string; the purpose of the x is so that postgres interprets them as hex strings when casting to a number)
    -- then converts the string to a 32 bit int
    -- Finally, all of the ints are summed
    sum(('x' || SUBSTRING(hash, 1, 8)) :: BIT(32) :: BIGINT) as sum1,
    -- Does the same as the column above, but with the next 8 characters
    sum(('x' || SUBSTRING(hash, 9, 8)) :: BIT(32) :: BIGINT) as sum2,
    sum(('x' || SUBSTRING(hash, 17, 8)) :: BIT(32) :: BIGINT) as sum3,
    sum(('x' || SUBSTRING(hash, 25, 8)) :: BIT(32) :: BIGINT) as sum4
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            md5 (
                -- When the column value is null, use a space
                COALESCE(md5('address' :: TEXT), ' ') ||
                COALESCE(md5('date'::TEXT), ' ')
            ) AS hash
        FROM
            example_table
    ) AS t;
```

B. Use SQLWorkbench/J’s [WbDataDiff](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/compare-commands.html#command-data-diff) data comparison tool to validate tables that don't have a PK or `UNIQUE` key. This method can show exact differences in the data between the source and target.

- The tool accepts an alternative key. The alternative key does not need to be declared as `UNIQUE` in the schema.

```
WbDataDiff -referenceProfile="source"
           -targetProfile="target"
           -referenceTables=lerg1
           -file=lerg1_diff.sql
           -includeDelete=true
           -alternateKey='lerg1=ocn_no'
           -excludeRealPK=true
           -showProgress=true
```

Comment: That technique of comparing the sums of per-line checksums is not reliable at all to compare table contents. Plus `md5('column'::text)` is wrong, the blog post meant `md5(column::text)`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Vérité ! If you're aware of a better way to compare table contents, l'd love to look into it.